# Merging a lot of xts objects

Tags: r, xts

I have some 'xts' objects, nearly 600, and I want to merge them to one 'xts'object.

The names of these objects are something like mfi0, mfi1, mfi2,... .
I can write merge command for a few objects such as

```
a<-merge(mfi0,mfi1,mfi2)
```

but my problem is that I couldn't write a `loop` or `lapply` for 600 objects, containing string "mfi" and a number, I tried `paste` but couldn't write.

Comment: `obj <- paste0("mfi", 1:600); obj_list<- lapply(obj, get); do.call(merge, obj_list)`

Comment: alternatively, `code <- paste0("merge(", paste0("mfi", 1:600, collapse=","), ")"); eval(parse(text=code))`

Comment: It does work. thank u so much.

Answer (score 2):

Where do these objects come from? It is better to use a list in the generation process instead of 600 seperate variables. Thus instead of having `mfi0`, `mfi1`, ..., `mfi600` you should have `mfi[1]`, `mfi[2]`, ..., `mfi[600]`.

Having all your data helps a lot in handling it. The merge procedure is now much simpler using your *own merge* command:

```
merged_mfi <- do.call(merge, mfi)
```

Or using a merge command that only handles two objects (i.e. the R merge for data.frames):

```
merged_mfi <- Reduce(merge, mfi[2:length(mfi)], mfi[1])
```

Comment: I want to calculate money flow index(MFI) for 636 tickers, I fetch the tickers with pdfetch package `sp<- pdfetch_YAHOO(identifiers[1:636], c("high","low","close","volume",from = as.Date("2012-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-12-30")`, then I used MFI from TTR package, I wrote two functions,`HLC<-function(i){sp[,(1+(4*i)):(3+(4*i))]}
Volume<-function(i){sp[,4*i+4]}`
`library(TTR)`
`for(i in 0:636)
 {  nam <- paste("mfi", i, sep = "")
 assign(nam,MFI(HLC(i),Volume(i),14))

}
`

Comment: Instead of `assign(nam, MFI(...))` you could use `mfi[i] <- MFI(...)` after initializing `mfi <- list()`

Comment: In almost any case it is bad practice to generate variable names while executing your code. Use list, arrays, matrices, data.frames, collections, dictionaries or any alike data structure in such circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Place all xts objects in a list `list.xts`. In your case, it will be a list of 600 elements each of which is a xts object. Then you can simply use

```
a = Reduce(f=merge.xts, list.xts)
```